# Find a value of $x$ such that $f(x) = y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $S_1$ be the sphere of radius $1$, centered at the origin. Let a be a number $> 0$. If $x$ is a point of the sphere $S_1$, then $ax$ is a point of the sphere of radius $a$, because $\|ax\| = a\|x\| = a$. Prove we get all points of the sphere of radius $a$ in this manner.

So, we are dealing with a situation where some $f: S_1 \to S_2$ as $f(x) = \|ax\| = a\|x\| = a$ is surjective.

Suppose $ax$ is a point on $S_2$. Then there's some $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. My question is how do I find that $x$?

$y = \|ax\| = a\|x\| = a$ suggests $\|x\| = \frac ya$. If so, what's $x$?

Comment: I think you mean "Suppose $y$ is a a point on $S_2$..."

Comment: Arent we given $ax$ to be a point on some sphere, presumably $S_2$?

Comment: No, you are trying to show that every point on $S_2$ is of the form $ax$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that $\|ax\|\in\mathbb{R}$ represents a length and in particular does not represent a point of the sphere $S_2$. The function you should be looking at is $f:S_1\rightarrow S_2$ such that $f(x)=ax$, which results in the easy answer $f^{-1}(y)=\dfrac{y}{a}$.

Comment: So, the rule $\|ax\| = a \|x\| = a$ maps the set $S_1 = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$  onto $\{ax_1, ax_2, \ldots, ax_n\}$. In general, $x \to ax$ which, then, translates to $f(x) = ax$ for all $x$. I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your function $f:S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ should be $f(x)=ax$. Now ley $y \in S_2$. define $x=\frac{y}{\|y\|}$. Note that $\|x\|=1$, so your $x \in S_1$ and you have surjectivity.